# Problemas ao abrir arquivo *.FDB pelo IBExpert

Tags: firebird

Bom dia!

Estou tentando puxar um banco de dados de um sistema antigo para ler as informações. Baixei e instalei o IBExpert, mas ao tentar abrir o arquivo, obtenho o seguinte erro: "unsupported on-disk structure for file, found 32779, support 10."

Obtenho esse erro, tanto no programa (a máquina ainda roda Windows XP por causa dele), como no IBExpress, como já informado.

Como proceder?

Comment: Verifica qual é a versão do banco, se por exemplo o banco for da versão Firebird 2.5 e você tentar abrir usando a versão Firebird 3.0 esse erro pode ocorrer. Então na hora de conectar pelo IBExpert informe o `Server Version` de acordo com a versão do seu banco.

Comment: Tentei isso na 1.5 e na 2.0... Não consegui... o sistema é antigo, o banco é mais novo e tem uma alteração no mês passado. Vou tentar nas outras versões. O programa citado é o mais recomendado? Tem alguma versão free? Não quero o programa, só preciso ler o banco de dados...

Comment: Nunca tive a curiosidade de ir atrás de outro que leia esse tipo de banco... Mas o IBExpert funciona "bem" para ler... Cara a versão mais atual do firebird está na 3.0 e se no seu IBExpert só aparece até a versão Firebird 2.0, procure a versão mais atualizada do IBExpert que aceite até a versão 3.0 do firebird e também acredito que o banco esteja na versão 2.5 então instale o Firebird 2.5 também... Firebird é bem chatinho de lidar

Comment: Problema de senha não é né? Porque eu peguei um banco que tinha senha, mas pelo que pesquisei, a senha não é no arquivo do banco, ela fica em outro arquivo, ou não!?

Comment: A versão do IBExpress tem até a 3.0, testei em todas, mas sem sucesso. Senha no banco? Será que eu receberia esta mensagem de erro? De qualquer forma, é uma alternativa. Estou colocando uma senha, que era tratada aqui como padrão, mas não estou obtendo sucesso.

Comment: Por hora, tenho recebido a mensagem "wrong or obsolete version". O sistema é antigo, tanto que nessa máquina onde ele está roda o Windows XP.